# SQL join on three tables, lines that exist in 2 tables but not the third

Tags: sql, join, db2, outer-join

Please I need your help.

Suppose that we have 3 tables A, B and C as shown in the image below:

[image]

I want to get lines in the table A that exist or not exist in table B, and lines in table C that exist or not exist in table B, using one sql request.

I have tried this but doesn't work :

```
SELECT A.ATS0804, C.ATS0207, A.ATS0959, A.ATS0802, B.ATS0827                                     
          FROM 
          ISUT183.ENS0042 B
          RIGHT JOIN ISUT183.ENS0038 A
          ON B.ENS0038K = A.ATS0804
          RIGHT JOIN ISUT183.EN00041 C  
          ON   B.EN00041K = C.AT02812

                WHERE ( C.ATS0207 = '0001757430' 
                   AND   B.ATS0823 = '9999-01-01'
                   AND   A.ATS0803 = '9999-01-01'
                   AND   A.ATS0959 = '61384352001' 
                 AND   A.ATS0802 ='01.01.2010'                             
                       ) ;
```

[image: Like this]

Answer (score 0):

If you test equality into table B in where clause, the left outer join or right outer join dont take null
You dont have join between A and C, then you can do a UNION ALL
but you must take columns of same type in selects clause (ID1 same type of ID2)

```
select * from ( 
select 'A-B' typejoin,  A.ID1 as IDA_OR_C, B.ID1 as IDB from A left outer join B on A.ID1=B.ID1
union all
select 'A-C' typejoin, C.ID2 as IDA_OR_C, B.ID2  as IDB from C left outer join B on C.ID2=B.ID2
) tmp
where ....
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but where can I put the where condition?

Answer (score 0):

you can do a cross join too:

```
with AB as (
select * from A left outer join B on A.ID1=B.ID1
),
AC as (
select * from C left outer join B on C.ID2=B.ID2
)
select * from AB CROSS JOIN AC
```

Answer (score 0):

use `where exists` and `where not exists` clauses